# Do Legendary Pokemon Respawn After The Elite Four?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation, pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I've heard that legendary Pokemon such as Kyogre/Groudon respawn after you defeat the Elite Four (if you didn't catch them). The only information that I can find seems to relate to the original version of the game.

Can players faint legendary Pokemon in order to progress the story and come back later to capture them?
And are there any exceptions?

The reasoning for this is some players, myself included, wish to finish the game in order to unlock post-game features *before* investing time/effort soft resetting for ideal natures in legendary Pokemon.

Please avoid spoilers where possible.

Comment: Mewtwo, Zygarde and even Snorlax did in XY. Unless Gamefreak took it out for god only knows why, I think they do

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Legendaries do respawn after defeating the Elite Four in Pokemon XY and ORAS.

Other than Rayquaza who you have to capture in order to progress a story sequence, all other legendaries that you haven't caught will respawn after beating the elite four.

Comment: I can now confirm from first hand experience that Kyogre/Groudon respawn after defeating the Elite Four.

Comment: Without giving away spoilers, does the legendary directly after Rayquaza respawn as well?

Comment: Yes! it respawns once you defeat E4 again, if you failed to capture it after rayquaza. Go to the top of sky tower again.

Comment: We both forgot to add, Latias/Lasios (version specific) do not respawn either as they are needed to progress the story.

Comment: @PhilD. Latios/Latias is a bit complicated. You get one of them for free, and you can catch the other one later on. The one you can catch behaves just like Rayquaza in that it won't disappear when defeated and can be challenged again right away.

Comment: Yes, though the one you are given is needed to progress the story so players who want a specific nature will be stuck here until they get it.