# Will Deoxys Re-appear if you didn't catch him when fighting him in space?

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

I accidentally killed Deoxys when he fought me because he ran out of PP and killed himself.

Does he respawn?

Comment: [Every uncaught legendary respawns if you defeat the Elite Four again.](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/193451/do-legendaries-respawn-after-the-elite-four-in-oras)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, he does! However, in order for that to happen, you must beat the Elite Four. You can repeatedly do this until you catch him. No matter how many times you knock him out, you can keep retrying after beating the Elite Four.